# Set grouped product to "out of stock" as soon as one of its products is out of stock?

Tags: stock, grouped-products

The heading describes it pretty well. How could I achieve that? I have a groupoed product with 2 included products. As soon as one of the included products is out of stock, the grouped product should be out of stock.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an observer `catalog_product_save_after` and then do something like...

```
<?php

class Observer
{
    public function catalogProductSaveAfter($observer)
    {
        /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product */
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();

        // we only want to operate on simple products
        if ($product->getTypeId() === 'simple') {

            // check if the product can be bought
            if (!$product->isSaleable()) {

                // get all parent ids of grouped parents
                // that this product belongs to
                $parentIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_grouped')
                    ->getParentIdsByChild($product->getId());
                if (count($parentIds) > 0) {

                    // get all parent products we want to now mark as oos
                    $parents = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                        ->getCollection()
                        ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $parentIds))
                        ->load();

                    /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product */
                    foreach ($parents as $parent) {
                        /** @var Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item $stockItem */
                        $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
                            ->loadByProduct($parent->getId());
                        $stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', 0);
                        $stockItem->save();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have done a basic test on the above code and it worked but I have not had time to as much testing as I would have like. Sorry about that. Should give you a good start though.

Comment: That looks good, just implemented it. Will that also run if the simple product quantity is reduced automatically if the product is bought?

Answer (score 1):

Possible implementation can be via Observer:

define a module

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><config>
<modules>
    <Vendor_Namspace>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Vendor_Namespace>
</modules>
<global>
    <helpers>
        <vendor_namespace>
            <class>Vendor_Namespace_Helper</class>
        </vendor_namespace>
    </helpers>
    <models>
        <vendor_namespace>
            <class>Vendor_Namespace_Model</class>
        </vendor_namespace>
    </models>
</global>
<frontend>
    <events>
        <catalog_product_save_before>
            <observers>
                <vendor_namespace>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>vendor_namespace/observer</class>
                    <method>checkStockFromSimpleBeforeSave</method>
                </vendor_namespace>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_before>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

Observer.php

```
<?php 
Class Vendor_Namespace_Model_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Observer {
    public function checkStockFromSimpleBeforeSave(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    if($product->getTypeInstance() != 'simple'){
         return;
    }
    $stock = null;
    $stockInstance = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item');
    $parents = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_grouped')->getParentIdsByChild($product->getId());
    if (count($parents) > 0) {
        $_parents = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $parents));

        foreach ($_parents as $parent) {
            $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($parent->getId());
            $stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', 0);
            $stockItem->save();
        }
    }        
}
```

code is not testet but should work

maybe some more events are necessary if a item is purchased

```
<events>
    <cataloginventory_stock_item_save_commit_after>
        <observers>
            <vendor_namespace>
                <class>vendor_namespace/observer</class>
                <method>catalogInventorySaveBefore</method>
            </vendor_namespace>
        </observers>
    </cataloginventory_stock_item_save_commit_after>
    <sales_model_service_quote_submit_before>
        <observers>
            <vendor_namespace>
                <class>vendor_namespace/observer</class>
                <method>subtractQuoteInventory</method>
            </vendor_namespace>
        </observers>
    </sales_model_service_quote_submit_before>
    <sales_model_service_quote_submit_failure>
        <observers>
            <vendor_namespace>
                <class>vendor_namespace/observer</class>
                <method>revertQuoteInventory</method>
            </vendor_namespace>
        </observers>
    </sales_model_service_quote_submit_failure>
    <sales_order_item_cancel>
        <observers>
            <vendor_namespace>
                <class>vendor_namespace/observer</class>
                <method>cancelOrderItem</method>
            </vendor_namespace>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_item_cancel>
    <sales_order_creditmemo_save_after>
        <observers>
            <vendor_namespace>
                <class>vendor_namespace/observer</class>
                <method>refundOrderInventory</method>
            </vendor_namespace>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_creditmemo_save_after>
</events>
```

and the method should be someting like:

```
public function catalogInventorySaveBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
    if ($this->isEnabled()) {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $_item = $event->getItem();

        if ((int)$_item->getData('qty') != (int)$_item->getOrigData('qty')) {

            $product = $_item->getProduct();
            $qty = $_item->getQty();
            $newQty = $_item->getOrigData('qty') - $_item->getQty();
            if($newQty < 1){
                $stockInstance = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item');
                $parents = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_grouped')->getParentIdsByChild($product->getId());
                if (count($parents) > 0) {
                    $_parents = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $parents));

                    foreach ($_parents as $parent) {
                        $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($parent->getId());
                        $stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', 0);
                        $stockItem->save();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

... and so on

Comment: Yes, but that does not run if the product is being bought, only when it is saved in the admin area. How can I modify that so it runs when an item is bought? Thanks!

Comment: @Arnie, it's not hard finding what events fire when. Try `Mage::dispatch`.

Comment: Did anyone find a solution for this?